# wall mount speaker's input jack

Tags: audio, built-ins

I bought a house built in 2000. I has wall built-in speakers, two in family room and 2 in game room. Both rooms have a jack panel, mounted in wall. They have rotating cups on them. I tried to put the 3.5 mm audio pin to it, but the pin is small. Any idea what kinda cable would work with them[image]

Comment: Can you get us a face-on shot of this arrangement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, there are holes in the side of the shaft. Put the wires through the holes and tighten down the ring to hold it in place.

Comment: Thats true. They have holes. Do I need to have receiver for them work? or is there any alternative? I want to use them with 3.5mm cable wire, so I can make them work with phone, laptop. How can I do that?

Comment: @user1631306 More than likely the headphone jack of a phone or laptop will not produce enough power to get sound out of the speakers. The small speakers you buy to connect to a computer contain a built-in amplifier. You will need to acquire an audio amplifier to use these speakers.

Answer (score 3):

Those are connections for *speakers*.

They are **not amplified**. To use a normal headphone signal (3.5 mm) with them, you will need an amplifier between your device and the wall connections.

Basically, you'd have two two-conductor wires going to the binding posts. The wires can connect 2 different ways:

- They can simply stripped of insulation at the end, inserted through the hole on the side of the post, and the nut would then be tightened down holding the wire in place.
- Alternatively, you could terminate the wires with [banana plugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_connector), which would then insert into the holes in the end of the posts.

[image]
<sub><sup>Image from https://www.crutchfield.com/S-OqNA1ABSJl6/learn/learningcenter/home/speakers_wire.html</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2):

### These are binding posts

These are binding-post connections -- you can connect stripped wire ends to them by screwing the stripped end down under the turning (nut) portion of the binding post, or use standard (4mm) banana plugs on the ends of your speaker leads that then plug into the socket in the middle of the binding post.

Comment: Do I need to have receiver for them work? or is there any alternative? I want to use them with 3.5mm cable wire, so I can make them work with phone, laptop

Comment: There are small amplifiers available for very little money. Search for 'class t amp' (which is technically a trademark, but has come to describe a category.)